# IE Developer Tools go to line shortkey

Tags: javascript, debugging, ie-developer-tools

I want to debug javascript in IE8 with IE Developer Toolbar but the script is too big, I have to scroll a lot.
Is there any way for quick jumping to lines like in Firebug `#linenumber`?
I didn't find any mention in help references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can either, but you can insert a break point on the line before and it should jump you to that line.

Answer (score 3):

Almost all Microsoft text apps use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> to pop up a dialog that accepts a line number.

To go to line 2011, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> , then type '2011' and enter.

Comment: Thx for the tip, but ctrl+g in this toolbar has a strange behavior: it's opened new window with html of the page in it and no debugging tools

Comment: In developer tools go to debugger tab and then ctrl+G